problem with insert GIF in python(TKinter)?
How to make it so that the gif was not in the main window (menu, greeting), but in the final window . I was able to insert a gif in the beginning of the program, but in the final window  did not work, how to make the final with a gif, if I have this code :
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def open_second_window():
    second_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    second_window.title("SECOND")
    second_window.state('zoomed')
 
    image_path = "1.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


    label = tk.Label(second_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo 
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(x=770, y=0)
 
    button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="ONE", command=lambda: open_four_window(second_window))

    button.place(x=308, y=82, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', wraplength=289, text="TWO", command=open_five_window)
    button1.place(x=688, y=82, anchor='ne')
    button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="THREE", command=open_threee_window)
    button.place(x=308, y=352, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="FOUR", command=open_threetenfive_window)
    button1.place(x=688, y=352, anchor='ne')


    tk.Label(second_window, font='Times 30', text="TEXT", fg="red").place(x=150, y=30)


    third_window.grab_set()
def open_four_window(second_window):

    second_window.destroy()

    four_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    four_window.title("THREE")
    four_window.state('zoomed')

    image_path = "2.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(four_window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo  
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    label.place(x=0, y=0)


    button = tk.Button(four_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="START", command=lambda: open_second_window())
    button.place(x=768, y=720, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(four_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="EXIT", command=animation)
    button1.place(x=1536, y=720, anchor='ne')



    third_window.grab_set()


...

def open_theend_window():
    # Создаем дочернее окно
    theend_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    theend_window.title("Второе окно")
    theend_window.state('zoomed')

    photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'road-sign-roadtrip.gif')
    lbl = tkinter.Label(theend_window ,image = photo)
    lbl.image = photo #keeping a reference in this line
    lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # Создаем метку для отображения изображения
    
     # Сохраняем ссылку на изображение



    # Создаем кнопку 
    button = tk.Button(theend_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="В начало", command=lambda: open_second_window())
    button.place(x=768, y=720, anchor='ne')
    button1 = tk.Button(theend_window,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="Выход", command=Close)
    button1.place(x=1536, y=720, anchor='ne')



    # Устанавливаем режим grab_set()
    third_window.grab_set()






5# Создаем главное окно
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Главное окно")
root.state('zoomed')


# Загружаем изображение 001.jpg
image_path = "40.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image.thumbnail((1, 1))

# Создаем метку для отображения изображения
label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
label.place(x=-3, y=0)

def Close(): 
    root.destroy() 

# Создаем кнопку "Далее"
button = tk.Button(root,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="NEXT", command=lambda: open_second_window())
button.place(x=768, y=720, anchor='ne')
button1 = tk.Button(root,height=1, width=33, font='Times 31', text="EXIT", command=Close)
button1.place(x=1536, y=720, anchor='ne')


tk.Label(root, font='Times 30', text="TEXT", fg="red").pack(padx=30, pady=30)
tk.Label(root, font='Times 30 italic', text="DESCRIPTION").place(x=600, y=77)

file = "road-sign-roadtrip.gif"
info = Image.open(file)

frames = info.n_frames  # number of frames

photoimage_objects = []
for i in range(frames):
    obj = tk.PhotoImage(file=file, format=f"gif -index {i}")
    photoimage_objects.append(obj)


def animation(current_frame=0):
    global loop
    image = photoimage_objects[current_frame]

    gif_label.configure(image=image)
    current_frame = current_frame + 1

    if current_frame == frames:
        current_frame = 0

    loop = root.after(50, lambda: animation(current_frame))

gif_label = tk.Label(root, image="")
gif_label.pack()

root.mainloop()

I made only the ability to play a GIF, but only in the main window, and I need to be in the final  window. In my program is quite a lot of functions (windows) and I did not write them, as it works.

Which is the final window?

line 22, in open_second_window
button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', wraplength=289, text="TWO", command=open_five_window)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'open_five_window' is not defined. Did you mean: 'open_four_window'?

line 24, in open_second_window
button = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="THREE", command=open_threee_window)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'open_threee_window' is not defined. Did you mean: 'open_theend_window'?

line 26, in open_second_window
button1 = tk.Button(second_window,height=4, width=12, font='Times 31', text="FOUR", command=open_threetenfive_window)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'open_threetenfive_window' is not defined. Did you mean: 'open_theend_window'?

line 33, in open_second_window
third_window.grab_set()
^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'third_window' is not defined

A possible solution is to create a new project with a gif and in the main script, after closing the program, the same window with the gif appears. It is necessary to enter from maincode import * (where maincode is the name of the script with the main code) and start the program from the script with the gif in the very beginning. In this way the main script is opened and when it is closed the window with the gif appears
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from maincode import *



root = Tk()

# Load the GIF image
gif = Image.open(“road-sign-roadtrip.gif”)

# Create a list of frames
frames = []
for i in range(gif.n_frames):
    gif.seek(i)
    frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(gif))

# Create a label widget to display the frames
frame_label = Label(root)
frame_label.pack()

# Define a function to play the animation
def play_animation(frame_idx):
    root.geometry(“600x600”)
    root.title(“End program”) 
    frame_label.config(image=frames[frame_idx])
    root.after(50, play_animation, (frame_idx+1) % len(frames))
    button1 = tk.Button(root,height=1, width=15, font='Times 31', text='Exit', command=Close)
    button1.place(x=470, y=431, anchor='ne')

# Start playing the animation
play_animation(0)


def Close(): 
    root.destroy() 

    
root.mainloop()


I think the logic is fine; there are just some typos that need fixing and some variables that need declaring.
Here are some examples of changes that made the gif animate for me:
def open_second_window():
    # omitting declarations…
    button1 = tk.Button(
        second_window, # omitting props…
        command=open_third_window) # Changed from undefined "open_five_window"
    button = tk.Button(
        second_window,
        command=open_third_window)# Typo: was "open_threee_window"


# Renaming def open_theend_window():
def open_third_window():
    # Updated from tkinter. to tk. since that's how you imported it
    third_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='road-sign-roadtrip.gif')
    button = tk.Button(
        third_window,
        command=open_second_window)

Judging from the usage I think you're developing a proof of concept for a tkinter app with images. If that's the case, I hope I helped you get closer! If this is intended for users, then it might be too challenging to understand.
I would recommend considering user stories for developing the use cases.
Regardless, I recommend developing with an editor that has syntax highlighting, like PyCharm or VSCode with python and autopep8 plugins. These tools can highlight typos and mistakes and save you a lot of time in the future.
Happy coding!

OP wanted how to make it so that the gif was not in the main window (menu, greeting)
